# Compile two classes from same package

Tags: java

There are two classes:

```
package chess;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("check");
        Board board = new Board();
    }
}
```

and

```
package chess; 

public class Board{
    public void initBoard() {
        System.out.println("Board");
    }

}
```

When I try to compile Main.java, it says:

```
javac src/chess/Main.java
src\chess\Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Board board = new Board();
        ^
  symbol:   class Board
  location: class Main
src\chess\Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Board board = new Board();
                          ^
  symbol:   class Board
  location: class Main
2 errors
```

Its very popular problem as I understood, but I can`t understand why it does not compile.
Their parent folder is "chess", they are in the same package so this Board class calling from Main is legal, I compile Board first, I compile them outside:

```
javac src/chess/Board.java
javac src/chess/Main.java
```

This error messages given on a second javac.
What else it can be? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you use a build system. IDEs tend to ship with them built in, so you should be able to get started fairly easily.

If you must continue to hurt yourself on this same stone, well, okay, then. There are some easy ways and some harder ways to do this on the command line.

Easy way: `javac src/chess/*.java`, simple enough.

Harder way: Include `src` as the `-sourcepath` option to `javac`, or, if you want to compile one file at a time and expand on the reachability as you go (this is silly; it means you can never have a class A that mentions class B, whilst B mentions class A - use `-sourcepath` or `*.java` for compiling instead), javac was not told where the classfiles are supposed to go, so it put them next to the source file. Which is not good, because you named your directory `src` and yet it contains not-source. It's bad if dirnames lie, so don't do this. Use the `-d` switch to tell javac where to put the class files, then use the `-cp` switch to tell javac where to find them:

```
## Option 1
mv src/chess chess # Fix bad names
rmdir src
javac chess/*.java
java -cp . chess.Main

## Option 2
mv src/chess chess
rmdir src
javac -sourcepath . chess/Board.java
javac -sourcepath . chess/Main.java
java -cp . chess.Main

## Option 3
mkdir bin
javac -cp bin -d bin src/chess/Board.java
javac -cp bin -d bin src/chess/Main.java
java -cp bin chess.Main

## The correct option
apt install maven
# or
brew install maven
```

Comment: Even I didn't totally realize why does your way works and mine don't, your tips are very useful, a lot of knew for me, and problem finally solved. Thank you very much